# Median Survival Rate

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm trying to use the survival package in R to run a log rank test on median survival rates - is that possible?  I'm using the code:

```
survdiff(surv(Age, Survival) ~ Treatment, data = GBM)
```

where Age = age at diagnosis; Survival = is how many years they survived; Treatment = is whether they received treatment (coded as 1 or 2)

If this is right, why am I getting the error:

```
Error in survdiff.fit(y, groups, strata.keep, rho) : 
  There is only 1 group
In addition: Warning message:
In Surv(GBM$Age, GBM$Survival) : Invalid status value, converted to NA
```

Does Treatment need to coded as 0 or 1 instead of 1 or 2?

Comment: your survival/event indicator is wrong. go look at `?surv`

Comment: You're right... I left out the "event" and it seemed to work... not sure if that is calculating it correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is no `surv` function in pkg:survival. It's `Surv`.

```
?Surv
```

It will not matter whether the covariate is coded 0/1 or 1/2. The estimate will describe the ratio of risk dependent on a difference of one unit. If you want to set up the `Surv` call to handle Age and duration then the event time should be Age+Survival. And of course you will need an event indicator.